# Returning attribute values without additional characters

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, values

I have this part of code inside of a plugin:

```py
Emptylist = []

def saveToList(self, layer, EmptyList):
        for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
            attributes = feat[self.pgLyr.currentText()]
            EmptyList.append(attributes)
```

when I run this code it stores attribute values to the list, but with additional information about the type of the field, so it returns (for example) `u'387'` if the field is text typed or `L387` if the field is Long typed.

Is there any way to get only 387 value, regardless of the additional information, without using a text splitting function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2.7 method called `encode("utf-8")`, will do this easily:

```py
Emptylist = []

 def saveToList(self, layer, EmptyList):
        for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
            attributes = (feat[self.pgLyr.currentText()]).encode("utf-8")
            EmptyList.append(attributes)
```

it will change the encoding to utf-8 so the `u'387'` in Unicode will be `387`.
nice and easy.